# Seed method in EF6 without overwriting values

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I'm overriding the DbMigrationConfiguration seed method in my project to get some default data for user permissions. At the moment, my data gets overwritten every time the migrations run.

Here is what I'm doing at the moment:

```
protected override void Seed(MyDbContext dbContext)
{
    List<Permission> permissions = PermissionFactory.CreatePermissions();
    dbContext.Permissions.AddOrUpdate(permissions);            
}
```

and the Permission entity:

```
public class Permission
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public bool Allow { get; set; }
}
```

I would like that data to be written once and only new entries added if they have a different Id from what is currently in the table. How do I do that so that my permissions aren't reset every time the migrations run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is a `AddIfNotExists`?

```
public static class EntityFrameworkExtension
{
    public static void AddIfNotExists<T>(
        this IDbSet<T> t, Func<T, object> func, params T[] objectsToAdd) 
        where T : class
    {
        foreach (var obj in objectsToAdd
            .Where(obj => !t.Select(func).Contains(func.Invoke(obj))))
                t.Add(obj);
    }
}
```

so you can call it with

```
dbContext.Permissions.AddIfNotExists(p=>p.Id,
    new Permission{/*values*/},
    new Permission{/*values*/},
    new Permission{/*values*/}
);
```

only new entries will be added

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks